# How do I activate a Steam key?

Tags: steam

I bought the Skyrim Legendary edition and it came with a steam code.  Where do I enter this Steam code?

Comment: Now, you can activate a Steam key through web browser by using [this link](https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey).

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you are on the Steam desktop client: Go to Library, then look at the bottom left corner for: "+ Add a Game..."  From there go to "Activate a Product on Steam" and follow the instructions.

Comment: To add an official source : https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352

Answer (score 15):

When logged into Steam, go to the top bar, click on on the small word "Games" (above Store and Library). In the drop down menu click on "Activate a Product on Steam...". On the pop up that appears, click on the "next" button on the bottom. After That click on the "I agree" button. Then enter in your Steam code into the text box that appears.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: Note that you **can't** do this from the mobile client or the website - you have to be on the proper desktop client.

Answer (score 1):

### https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey

Easier to activate through the website than through the app.